# Create dynamic Expression lambda from two others (chaining the Expressions)

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, runtime, expression

Given a lambda that takes an Identification object, and returns a property:

```
Expression<Func<Identification, object>> fx = _ => _.Id;
```

And a conversion lambda that converts an object into an Identification instance:

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
Expression @new = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(p, typeof(Identification)), p);
```

How do I build a new lambda that executes `@new` (getting out the Identification Instance) and passes the result into `fx`. I need `@new`'s result to bind to the first parameter of `fx` somehow, and I cannot find an example.

I need the result to be an `Expression`, it should be of type `Expression<Func<object, object>>` and it should convert the inbound parameter to an `Identification` and then get the `Id` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, note that this is easier if you type `@new` appropriately, i.e.:

```
LambdaExpression @new = ...
```

since that provides easy access to `@new.Body` and `@new.Parameters`; that done,
`Expression.Invoke` can be useful here:

```
var combinedParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
var combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
    Expression.Invoke(fx,
        Expression.Invoke(@new, combinedParam)), combinedParam);
```

although for a cleaner expression, you can also use `ExpressionVisitor` to completely replace the inner expressions:

```
var injected = new SwapVisitor(fx.Parameters[0], @new.Body).Visit(fx.Body);
var combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(injected,@new.Parameters);
```

with:

```
class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

what this does is:

- inspect the `fx.Body` tree, replacing all instances of `_` (the parameter) with the `@new.Body` (note that this will contain references to the `o` parameter (aka `p`)
- we then build a new lambda from the replaced expression, re-using the same parameters from `@new`, which ensures that the values we injected will be bound correctly

Comment: Hi, I actually came close to trying exactly that, but it looked all wrong in linqpad. The final expression tree looks horrific, even when simplified - but it does the job perfectly thanks. If you do it all at once the compiler generates a neater tree. (object p) => ((Identification)p).Id you get Convert(Convert(p).Id) which is really neat. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jim - have you refreshed? the second version creates exactly that `o => Convert(Convert(o).Id)`, rather than `o => Invoke(_ => Convert(_.Id), Invoke(o => Convert(o), o))`

Comment: I have used the visitor, and generated the new expression. It works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using the code from [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873616/57611), you can simplify this really nicely with a helper function:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper {
    public static Expression<Func<TFrom, TTo>> Chain<TFrom, TMiddle, TTo>(
        this Expression<Func<TFrom, TMiddle>> first,
        Expression<Func<TMiddle, TTo>> second
    ) {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, TTo>>(
           new SwapVisitor(second.Parameters[0], first.Body).Visit(second.Body),
           first.Parameters
        );
    }

    private class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly Expression _from;
        private readonly Expression _to;

        public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
            _from = from;
            _to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
            return node == _from ? _to : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now look how clean that is!

```
var valueSelector = new Expression<Func<MyTable, int>>(o => o.Value);
var intSelector = new Expression<Func<int, bool>>(x => x > 5);
var selector = valueSelector.Chain<MyTable, int, bool>(intSelector);
```

And it works with Entity Framework and other things that need a clean `Expression` that doesn't try to invoke a `Func` within it.

Comment: This answer does not rank highly enough on Google. Though searching extensively I only found this question and this elegant answer from a blog post that linked it. Here's hoping new activity might help future searchers.